# CSS Style Not Being Applied Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

When a form is submitted I'm loading a page from the controller using views that are split into template sections:

```
$this->load->view('templates/header');
$this->load->view('templates/navigation');
$this->load->view('templates/page');
$this->load->view('templates/footer');
```

I'm loading a custom CSS file in the header.php file which works fine, I get a 200 response in the console when the page loads, so the CSS file is being found.

My problem is that the CSS is not being applied on page.php even though the page is fully built as it should be.

I've checked Google, the Codeigniter documentation and I cannot find any reason why this would happen.

## SOLVED

Found the issue... turned out to be a simple browser caching issue. A simple ctrl+f5 fixed this.

I hope this helps anyone else looking.

Comment: Gotta be something simple. Check the very basics of what you're doing. Is the css file properly loaded / isn't cached. Are the rules applying to whatever is on the page, etc.

Comment: You cannot be using CI version 2 and 3 at the same time.  Please do not tag-spam.  Edited.  Thanks.

Comment: @SergChernata It was a caching problem, very strange! Suddenly the cache decided to hang for some reason. I hit ctrl+f5 just to test and it worked! All working fine now, thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Sparky Sorry about that! Won't happen again.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue... turned out to be a simple browser caching issue. A simple ctrl+f5 fixed this.

I hope this helps anyone else looking.